# Does w3wp.exe keep extra crash information

Tags: iis, w3wp

I have created several websites that run from ISAPI dll's, which runs smoothly in most cases. Only on one server I get events like these:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Application Error
Event Category: (100)
Event ID:   1000
Date:       28/04/2011
Time:       3:04:21
User:       N/A
Computer:   DIGIPROMNG
Description:
Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 6.0.3790.3959, faulting module unknown, version 0.0.0.0, fault address 0x01bdd762.
```

Does `w3wp.exe` keep extra crash information like stack dumps, or for which application pool it was running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can find information in the log file.

```
 C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1
```

... or ...

```
 C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\W3SVC1
```

---

Another possibility is to use Microsofts IIS crash tool, or if possible debug the process with Visual Studio.

[IIS Debug Diagnostic Tool v1.2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798)